# Why doesn't a UITableView scroll until I have 2 additional rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

**Scenario:**  
Embedded UITableView in a standard UIViewController's view. 
Three (3) 80-pt rows fill the UITableView.

**Problem:** 
UITableView doesn't scroll until the number of rows > 5.

I've tested this by varying the number of displayed rows and attempted to scroll.  Three (3) rows fills the UITableView.  Four (4) fills but doesn't scroll.  Ditto with five (5).   But Six or greater... I can scroll.

Why can't I scroll for the 4 or 5 - count rows?

Comment: code and images would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView (from which UITableView inherits) has a `alwaysBounceVertical`
property. If you set this to true, either in code or Storyboard, the table view will be vertically 'scrollable' regardless of how many rows it has.

Comment: I set (checked) the corresponding UIScrollView which SOLVED the problem; albeit it scrolls even when the UITableView is not filled.  I can probably unchecked this for row counts < UITableView's view size.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something wrong where you set the height of your table or where you set it's scroll properties not to bounce.

I've just tried it and I can scroll with 2 or 3 cells. 
If your tableview has enough room to show all the cells, it wouldn't scroll.

[image: image for example]

Comment: It was the missing 'bounce' property under UITableView's UIScrollView parent class.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee glad to have helped. :)